# Jackson not being imported with gradle

Tags: java, json, gradle, jackson

I am trying to parse some objects to JSON files, and apparently I can import some phantom libraries (more on that later) but when I try to execute my code, it fails here:

```
String jsonStr = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(adv);
```

**With this exception:**

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonView`

### My build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'com.myGroup.util'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.0'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.4'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.4'
    
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.0.1'
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: '2.0.1'
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.0.1'
    
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

And in my Main.java class I can do this import:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.*;
```

with no problems, the only issue is that when I put the mouse on top it displays that no JavaDoc has been found, fishy... I even tried removing all the dependencies from my gradle.build file and it will still let me import the package but it seems like it is empty.

Comment: What version of gradle are you using? Recent versions of gradle don't use the group/name/version syntax, but rather `implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.0.1'`  Also, how are you executing your code?  Are you creating a fat jar and running it, in which there's something wrong with the jar creation and you need to add `id: application` to the plugins block of your gradle instead of the 'java' since that includes 'java' -- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the comment, I think the issue was that I was not importing the jars properly... I still have a lot of learning of Gradle to do :D

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, while taking gradle dependency as

```
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.jackson-dataformat-xml:2.13.0'
```

But apparently, it has to be declared as @PickedBrain pointed out

```
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.13.0'
```

Gradle dependency syntax

```
implementation '{domain/group}:{package/name}:{version}'
```